# How to replace the contents of the cookie with jwt token?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, jwt

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0

`HttpContext.SignInAsync` generates the cookie and sends it in the response.

1. In the browser when I look at the cookie it contains jumbled alphabets - so is the cookie encrypted?
2. Assuming I generate a JWT upon successful user credential check, then I can return the JWT directly without making use of `HttpContext.SignInAsync`. Does `HttpContext.SignInAsync` suppose any method so that I can put the JWT into the cookie so that I don't have to return it directly?